# display or hide the button on select all checkbox of a webgrid

Tags: jquery

how can i revise my code to display the button on selectall and hide the button when deselct the selectall . it is working fine on firefox but have problem in chrome.

```
 $('#selectall').click(function () {
                                    $('.selectedId').prop('checked', isChecked('selectall'));
                                });

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {

        if ($('.selectedId:checked').length >= 1) {
            if ($('#AdvancedOption').is(':hidden'))
                $('#AdvancedOption').fadeIn('fast');
            if ($('.selectedId:checked').length == 1) {
                $('.toolbar1').fadeIn('fast');
            }
            else
                $('.toolbar1').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.toolbar2').fadeIn('fast');
        }

        else {
            $('.toolbar1').fadeOut('fast');
            $('#AdvancedOption').fadeOut('fast');
        }

    });
```

here is the related Html

```
<div id="AdvancedOption" style="display: none" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 btn-group-sm">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger toolbar2 deleteAccount" title="Delete this account" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning toolbar1 editTeam" title="Edit this account" role="button" style="display:none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: What's the button's name? Can you post the relevant HTML code?

Comment: ok i am updatig my code

Comment: have a look on html code.

Comment: What does your checkbox HTML look like?  Is `.selectedId` the class that you are using for your checkboxes and `#AdvancedOption` the div that you want to toggle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider following sample:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="chk-container">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />Select All
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" class="selectedId" />Checkbox 1
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" class="selectedId" />Checkbox 2
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check3" class="selectedId" />Checkbox 3
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check4" class="selectedId" />Checkbox 4
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check5" class="selectedId" />Checkbox 5
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="AdvancedOption" style="display: none;" class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 btn-group-sm">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger toolbar2 deleteAccount" title="Delete this account" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning toolbar1 editTeam" title="Edit this account" role="button" style="display: none;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.chk-container li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7E7E7;
    padding: 2px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    /* Check all checkboxes if 'Select All' is clicked */
    if (this.id == 'selectAll') {
        var isChecked = this.checked;
        $('.selectedId').each(function() {
            this.checked = isChecked;
        });
    }

    /* Check / Uncheck 'Select All' checkbox if all the checkboxes are checked / unchecked */
    if ($('.selectedId:checked').length == $('.selectedId').length) $('#selectAll').prop('checked', true);
    else $('#selectAll').prop('checked', false);

    /* Toggle controls on the basis of selected checkboxes */
    if ($('.selectedId:checked').length >= 1) {
        $('#AdvancedOption').fadeIn('fast');

        if ($('.selectedId:checked').length == 1) {
            $('.toolbar1').fadeIn('fast');
        } else {
            $('.toolbar1').fadeOut('fast');
            $('.toolbar2').fadeIn('fast');
        }
    } else {
        $('.toolbar1').fadeOut('fast');
        $('#AdvancedOption').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

Updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qvdzgLrx/1/)

Comment: @Miranda: Do you need something like this?

Comment: yes @prakash but i have to implement my conditions also and want to revise my code. and how can i implement select all functionality of yours can you tell me that.

Comment: i have updated my code. what you told me i put that logic into my code its working at very first time but again when i deselect that select all and again select select all its only visible for mili sec.

Comment: Thank you for ur suggestion and if possible then help me on my current issue, i am gonna accept your answer.

Comment: @Miranda: I have updated my answer, considering your requirement. Please view updated code and DEMO.